# Resolve ${karaf.home} supplied by properties placeholder in Camel

Tags: properties, apache-camel, apache-karaf, properties-file

I'm trying to provide a filepath for PGP encryption keys from a property.

```
.setHeader("CamelPGPDataFormatKeyFileName")
.constant("file:{{devo_keyringUri}}")
```

The `{{devo_keyringUri}}` is defined as something like `${karaf.base}/etc/devKeyring.gpg`

I assumed that `${karaf.base}` would be resolved by the properties component, but it didn't work. I get an `java.io.FileNotFoundException - ${karaf.base}/etc/devKeyring.gpg`

So it resolves the placeholder but does not resolve the 'nested' variable.

What do I need to do, to get the resolved path in `${karaf.base}`?

```
Camel Version is 2.13.2
Karaf Version is 2.3.9
```

EDIT

It also didn't work with newer versions:

```
Camel Version is 2.15.3
Karaf Version is 4.0.1
```

Comment: Try upgrading Camel its an old version

Comment: @ClausIbsen Thanks for the hint. Now tried with Camel 2.15.3 on Karaf 4.0.1 but also had no luck (same results as described).

Comment: Try with `{{sys:karaf.base}}/etc/devKeyring.gpg`

Answer (score 0):

Constant() is **not** the right method here. Try this:

```
setHeader("CamelPGPDataFormatKeyFileName", simple("file:${properties:devo_keyringUri}")
```

More infos [here](https://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html).

Comment: I tried with simple language but it didn't solve the problem (same result).

Comment: Are you sure your wildcard expression is correct? Don't use the {{}} notation.